# Proper Python packaging with external package dependencies

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

Let's suppose I have a project that depends on packages that should only be installed via the systems package manager (e.g. bindings to C libraries), so that `install_requires` is not working.

Currently, I try to import said packages in `setup.py` and call `sys.exit()` with a positive exit code if the import fails. Is this good practice or are there better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create native system packages (`deb`, `rpm`, etc.) and describe the dependencies in it (which are the C libraries in your case). You can check the [Debian packages packing manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html) (or packages for some other manager, depending on the system you're using).

Comment: The dependencies _are_ installable via `apt`, `yum` etc. But I need to find a way to specify these dependencies in my `setup.py`. Or just fail gracefully if they are not installed.

Comment: Yes, if the dependencies are installed this way, you probably should create apt and yum versions for your package.

Comment: I was thinking about this and came to the conclusion that this is technically a correct solution but requires a lot of effort from my side. This is especially true for very small and "not-so-important" projects.